# NextJS 13 App Router - translating notfound route

Tags: next.js, internationalization

Is there a way to generate a totally static SSG notfound page in multiple languages? (no middleware usage)

---

ideally the file structure is:

```
App
└── [locale]
    ├── not-found.tsx
    └── [[slug]]
        └── page.tsx
```

the main issue is that from not-found.tsx i can't find a way to access the [locale] param

Comment: sorry, no :( there was a same post in github, where somebody proposed a suggestion, but it's not dynamic